# Sort a list of number by last 2 digits

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to sort list2=[311, 409, 313, 202, 303, 410, 401, 105, 407, 408]
to 
[101 301 401 202 407 408 409 410 311 313]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the last two digits using the remainder operator, then use the digits as key of [sorted](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted):

```
a = [311, 409, 305, 104, 301, 204, 101, 306, 313, 202, 303, 410, 401, 105, 407, 408]
result = sorted(a, key=lambda x: (x % 100, x))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[101, 301, 401, 202, 303, 104, 204, 105, 305, 306, 407, 408, 409, 410, 311, 313]
```

As you want to ties to be solved using the actual value the key is a tuple of the last two digits and the actual value.

Comment: Will get you unexpected results for negative integers in `a`.